# Java String можно ли пройти всю строку последовательно?

Tags: java

Есть строка: `%a(444)%b(sdasd)%c(dsada)`

Текст в скобках произвольный. Можно ли как-то пройти всю строку, последовательно "вычленяя" все подстроки (`%a(444); %b(sdasd); %c(dsada)` ) и в зависимости от того, какая у нас подстрока встретилась, выполнять определённые действия со строкой (например удалять найденную подстроку и выводить на консоль `Yes`)? Между подстроками других символов нет, т.е `подстрока1подстрока2подстрока3`. Т.е нужно некое подобие цикла по строке:

```
if(строка1) {};
if(строка2) {};
if(строка3) {};
```

Можно ли как-то так сделать???

Comment: Цикл по строке? 

IMHO это очень просто:

    String s;
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      Char  c = s.charAt(i);
      ...
    }

или я не понял Вашего вопроса?

Comment: @avp, мне нужно работать не с одним символом, а с набором символов. 
Например в строке "qwertyqw". Если я встречаю "qwe", то нужно заменить его на "1", а если "ty", то заменить его на 2. И в итоге должно получиться: "1r2qw". string split не подходит вроде бы

Comment: @dayz2dayz, прежде всего -- String в Java **не изменяемы!!!** ([String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) это встроенный static object).

Вы можете сделать *новую* строку из символов (подстрок) существующей и присвоить результат той же переменной, но изменить содержимое строки невозможно (стандартными средствами, не обращаясь к JNI).

--

Документацию-то вообще читаете?

Comment: @dayz2dayz: [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) и [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) вам в помощь. Читайте документацию, как уже было сказано.

Answer (score 1):

Функция split string Вам в помощь. Да и вообще посмотрите функции работы со строками и массивами, так много полезного встретите.